# Reverse Geocoding for Israel

Tags: geocoding, reverse

Where can i find a free service for reverse geocoding a coordinate in israel to get a street address? the google api web service doesnt give me a street address in israely coordinates...
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by israeli coordinates, a certain system?

Comment: I mean a coordinates that are located in isreal, a coordinates which are inside a street.

Comment: would be nice to update this with the streets update for Google Map API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also searching.. found no free service, but Waze have a nice one for pay.

This is example I got from them:

```
http://rgc.waze.co.il/GeoCoding/decode?token=123&x=34.8735080868463&y=32.05829587571&r=0.001&max=3

Where:
    token = is the token assigned to you (currently use 123)
    x = Lon.
    y = Lat.
    r = distance to search the address (angle - 1 deg = 111.11 KM)
    max = the number of max results

<result>
<address id="52778" type="1" street="גני תקווה" house="22">
  </address>
<address id="52776" type="1" street="קישון" house="22">
  </address>
<address id="52775" type="1" street="קישון" house="18">
  </address>
</result>
```

Answer (score 4):

Checkout
[Find nearest Intersection and Find nearby Streets](http://www.geonames.org/maps/osm-reverse-geocoder.html#findNearestIntersectionOSM) from GeoNames.org

For example:

```
http://ws.geonames.org/findNearestIntersectionOSM?lat=32.081&lng=34.781
```

returns:

```
<geonames>
 <intersection>
  <street1>אבן גבירול</street1>
  <highway1>tertiary</highway1>
  <street2>בלוך</street2>
  <highway2>tertiary</highway2>
  <lat>32.0813665</lat>
  <lng>34.7813189</lng>
  <distance>0.05</distance>
 </intersection>
</geonames>
```

Comment: but this doesn't give a house number

Comment: It's the closest one I found for free. the only fully functional one is waze for now ro atlas, but atlas is costy.