# looking for a reverse map api that returns address from geolocation longlitude and latitude - in Israel

Tags: api, geolocation

google maps api has this functionality but not in israel
I searched this answer
[Reverse Geocoding for Israel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949464/reverse-geocoding-for-israel)
but I hoped there is something new

edit:
I'll answer my own question
seems that http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html has sort of an answer
not an exact street pinpoint like google maps but a couple of near hits like: streets nearby, near street intersection etc

disappointing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question: seems that google implented reverse geocoding support to israel too - in google maps api v3